# Error With ROOM Database in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, dao

I am a beginner in android and I am trying to build an app that could fetch from an api but I am facing an error related to Dao , I also tried to read and understand the error but was unable to ,  please help me with my error , I am getting this error whenever I try to work with Dao and coroutines

[Here is the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPxWA.png)

[Here is my dao code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwuKy.png)

[here is the error location to which i was directed when i clicked on the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjZAZ.png)

[Article class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMMY1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution but cannot say its the right one , if anyone have any info regarding then please share

I removed the suspend functions in the dao class
and changed my appCompat dependency to 1.2.0

Answer (score 0):

You should insert `@ColumnInfo` top of your DB column like this

@Entity(tableName = "coin_price")
@Parcelize
data class CoinPrice(

```
@PrimaryKey
@ColumnInfo(name = "id")
val id: Int,

@ColumnInfo(name = "price")
var price: String? = null

) : Parcelable
```

Comment: so i should make the class Parcelable or just column info should be added

Comment: i added column info but still the same error is coming

Comment: please give me more information to understand your problem